# How to inflate Dialog with system preference screen (for example Settings/.wifi AdvancedSettings)?

Tags: android, inflate

I can inflate Custom or Alert Dialog with other layout by

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService  (LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog,null);
...
builder.setView(layout)
...
AlertDialog alert = builder.create(); 
...
alert.show();
```

And I know how call System settings dialog by Intent:

```
Intent MyIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_IP_SETTINGS);
startActivity(MyIntent);
```

So I have question How can I inflate Dialog with system settings screen that I calling by intent? I want show system screen like Dialog window. How can I perform operation `builder.setView()` for system settings screen and call it with Intent? Is it possible?